# check a int/string contains specific digits in it using regex

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I have a string/integer `X: 912035374356789`

i want to check if X contains : `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0`

occurrence order is not matter

How do check it using regular expression.
if there is any algorithm please mention, because i want to do it in minimum time complexity

```
Example
ex1: 61243456092 //false 7 & 8 not present
ex2: 864123456789 //false 0 is not present
ex3: 987601234567 //true all present
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string contains only digits then you can count the number of unique digits in it

```
long count = string.chars().distinct().count();
```

and check if count is 10

Example

```
String ex1 = "61243456092";
String ex2 = "864123456789";
String ex3 = "987601234567";

System.out.println(ex1.chars().distinct().count());
System.out.println(ex2.chars().distinct().count());
System.out.println(ex3.chars().distinct().count());
```

yields

> 8
>   9
>   10

Comment: Although OP is looking for a regex solution, I would go with this solution because a regex solution for this won't be as efficient as this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex blocks that ensure `1` is there at least once.

```
(?=.*1)
```

Now, in your case, you can combine all of them (positive look ahead)

```
(?=.*0)(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)
```

Demo: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Ct8cb/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `string.contains` like this:

```
public static boolean checkString(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (!str.contains(Integer.toString(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I realize it's not a regular expression like you wanted, but I think it's the simplest answer.